# how to use ggtext to color axis data labels in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I have come across `ggtext` package from https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/ to color axis data labels using  `element_markdown()` and tried to color my axis labels but failed.

**Code (without ggtext)**:

```
library(tidyverse)

read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_stack_limited.csv") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Cases_type, y = Country.Region)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Cases_size, color = Cases_type), fill="#f8f2e4", stroke=3) +
  # theme_minimal() +
  theme_wsj() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", family = "serif", size = 20),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 9)) +

  scale_color_tableau(palette = "Tableau 10") +
  # scale_color_wsj(palette = "colors6") +
  
  facet_wrap(~Date) +
  labs(title = "Top 5 Countries for all type of Daily cases",
       subtitle = "For Latest 7 days separated by each date",
       caption = "created by ViSa (SciArt!!)") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

**Now if I add `ggtext` to color the `x-axis` data labels then I am getting error**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

color = c("#2596be", "#f28e2b", "#e15759")

read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_stack_limited.csv") %>% 
  
  mutate(Cases_type = glue("<i style='color:{color}>{Cases_type}</i>'")) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Cases_type, y = Country.Region)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Cases_size, color = Cases_type), fill="#f8f2e4", stroke=3) +
  # theme_minimal() +
  theme_wsj() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", family = "serif", size = 20),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 9)) +
  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown()) +
  scale_color_tableau(palette = "Tableau 10") +
  # scale_color_wsj(palette = "colors6") +
  
  facet_wrap(~Date) +
  labs(title = "Top 5 Countries for all type of Daily cases",
       subtitle = "For Latest 7 days separated by each date",
       caption = "created by ViSa (SciArt!!)") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you tried to `glue` your `color` vector of length 3 with your `Cases_type` column which is a vector of length 105. Instead make `color` a named vector and use `color[Cases_type]` which ensures that you assign the right colors. Additionally there was a missing quote in your `glue` statement.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)
library(ggthemes)

color = c(Daily_cases = "#2596be", Daily_deaths = "#f28e2b", Daily_recovered = "#e15759")

d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_stack_limited.csv") %>% 
  mutate(Cases_type = glue("<i style='color: {color[Cases_type]}'>{Cases_type}</i>'")) 

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Cases_type, y = Country.Region)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Cases_size, color = Cases_type), fill="#f8f2e4", stroke=3) +
  #theme_minimal() +
  theme_wsj() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", family = "serif", size = 20),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "plain", family = "serif", size = 9)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown()) +
  scale_color_tableau(palette = "Tableau 10") +
  # scale_color_wsj(palette = "colors6") +
  facet_wrap(~Date) +
  labs(title = "Top 5 Countries for all type of Daily cases",
       subtitle = "For Latest 7 days separated by each date",
       caption = "created by ViSa (SciArt!!)") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @stefan for helping me out. I wasn't sure how to assign colors according to cases type. thanks for showing me the correct way !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
"<i style='color:{color}>{Cases_type}</i>'"
```

to

```
"<i style='color:{color}'>{Cases_type}</i>"
```

Comment: thank @Stéphane Laurent this was a silly mistake by me but there were more issues as mentioned below.